# Connection in Paradox Database via ODBC

Tags: locking, odbc, paradox

I've been struggling very hard to make this work. I'm using a software that uses paradox database, which I never used.

My problem is: I can open the program in multiple machines on the same time, but i can't seem to connect via ODBC when there is a program open in any machine (a .lck file maybe?). When noone is using the program I can connect without problems...

I understand that the lock file is there to protect the database integrity, but i wish just to make select commands via SQL directly into it... Is there any way to do it? A read-only connection maybe?

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I am living with this work around solution on the implementations of software I do where I work.

To make it work:

1. On the server machine of the paradox database, you have to create a new partition with the same letter where you will map on the client machines;
2. Share the unit drive;
3. On the client machines, map a new drive to the shared drive (repeating: the letter must be the same than in the server machine);
4. Put the database files in this drive;
5. Create the ODBC paradox system data source (it must be the 32 bit wizard) using the new directory for both Folder and Network folder;
6. Delete the existing .NET and .LCK before testing;
7. test...

I've read something about setting AUTO ODBC to TRUE on BDE too...